# PySpark statistics on values

Tags: python, json, pyspark

I have around 5 million records that are in JSON format that has various customer data fields:

```
{'customer_name': 'John','customer_type': 'A', 'number_of_visits':10, ....}
{'customer_name': 'Mary','customer_type': 'A', 'number_of_visits':2, ....}
{'customer_name': 'Ann','customer_type': 'B', 'number_of_visits':5, ....}
...
```

I wrote a filter that removes invalid JSON records and mapper that takes only 'customer_type' and 'number_of_visits' fields, so the output of the filter and mapper is:

```
[('A',10), ('A',2), ('B',5)...]
```

What I would like to get is something like this:

Customers of type 'A' go shopping 10 times per year X times, go shopping 2 times per year Y times, customers of type 'B; go shopping 5 times per year Z times...

What I attempted is groupByKey, which then groups all customers of type 'A', 'B', etc. together, but I am not sure how and if it is possible to get the type of statistics that I need.

(I initially attempted to return a dictionary instead list of tuples and then use keyBy(lambda row: row['customer_type'), but never was able to proceed further)

Comment: How do you intended to put them together? What is the result you want

Comment: There is a finite number of customer types (less than 20) and each customer can shop max 20 times, so I need a printout, line by line, nothing fancy

Comment: So you just want to print out your list?

Comment: And what problem are you getting with this

Comment: I can't get the statistics. My issue is not printing, it's how to get the results. I do groupByKey, but then I need to calculate the statistics on each key

Comment: Are you asking how to access elements in your array? You can essentially treat it like a 2d array

Comment: No, sorry if my question wasn't clear. I am asking what to do after I do groupByKey. I am not able to proceed further and obtain the results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is loop through the array and add up the values. For example:

```
from collections import defaultdict
statistics={}
for (customer_type, habits) in groupedList:
    statistics[customer_type]=defaultdict(int)
    for times in habits:
        statistics[customer_type][times]+=1
```

statistics will end up containing a nested dict that looks something like this {'A':{10:1, 2:1}, 'B':{5:1}}. So the first key is the customer type and the second is the amount of times they went shopping. The value is how many people shopped x amount of times in a year